# Media Query max-width rules are working for greater dimension than set up

Tags: css, media-queries

Looking for your help and advices.
 I'm using Media queries to make website responsive. I have a problem with menu. 
 I used `@media (max-width: 1083px)` to set styles and it's working well, but some rules are working till `1183px`. I don't understand why... To fix it I tried to rewrite rules using  `@media (min-width: 1083px) and (max-width: 1181px)` but this didn't help.  If I set styles suing `@media (max-width: 1181px)` it is rewriting rules inside `@media (max-width: 1083px)` .

HTML:

```
<div class="top-menu">
        <div class="menu-mask"></div>
        <div class="container">
        <span class="hamburger-menu visible-xs visible-sm"><img src="/source/img/menu.png" alt="Menu"></span>
          <div class="logo">
         <div class="ev_logo">        
            <svg version="1.1" id="" class="" xmlns:x="&ns_extend;" xmlns:i="&ns_ai;" xmlns:graph="&ns_graphs;"
                 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 59 59"
                 style="enable-background:new 0 0 59 59;" xml:space="preserve">

                <g id="ev_round">
                    <path id="XMLID_3000_" class="st0" d="M29.5,0.7c-16,0-29,12.9-29,28.8s13,28.8,29,28.8s29-12.9,29-28.8S45.5,0.7,29.5,0.7z
                     M29.5,54.5c-13.9,0-25.1-11.2-25.1-25s11.3-25,25.1-25c13.9,0,25.1,11.2,25.1,25S43.4,54.5,29.5,54.5z"/>
                </g>
                <g id="ev_letters">
                    <path id="XMLID_2996_" class="st1" d="M50.6,26.7C49.3,17,41.4,9.3,31.5,8.4v42.2c9.9-0.9,17.9-8.5,19.2-18.3l-2.8-2.8L50.6,26.7z
                         M35.4,45.9V31.4h8.9l2.3,2.3C45.1,39.3,40.9,44,35.4,45.9z M44.4,27.5h-9.1V13.1c5.5,1.9,9.8,6.6,11.2,12.3L44.4,27.5z"/>
                    <path id="XMLID_2993_" class="st2" d="M8.4,26.7l2.8,2.8l-2.8,2.8c1.3,9.7,9.3,17.4,19.2,18.3v-3.8c-7.4-0.8-13.4-6.2-15.1-13.2
                        l2.3-2.3h12.8V8.4C17.6,9.3,9.7,17,8.4,26.7z M23.6,13.1v14.4h-9.1l-2.1-2.1C13.9,19.7,18.1,15,23.6,13.1z"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="ph-lift hidden-xs hidden-sm">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#" data-title="Главная">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="/news/" data-title="Новости">Новости</a></li>
                <li><a href="/afisha/" data-title="Афиша">Афиша</a></li>
                <li><a href="/biography/" data-title="Биография">Биография</a></li>
                <li><a href="/photo/" data-title="Материалы">Материалы</a></li>
                <li><a href="/staff/" data-title="Коллектив">Коллектив</a></li>
                <li><a href="/visitor/" data-title="Гостевая">Гостевая</a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="#" data-title="Магазин">Магазин</a></li>-->
                <li><a href="/contacts/" data-title="Контакты">Контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>        
        <!--<div class="search"><div class="search-icon"></div></div>-->
        <div class="login">
          <img id="imgLogin" src="/source/img/login-icon.png" alt="">
          <img id="imgAva" style="display: none;" src="{{ avatar }}" alt="">
          <div class="login-ef" data-vn-action="dlgLogin">
          <span>Войти</span>
          </div>
          <div class="logout" style="display: none;" data-vn-action="logout">
          <span data-title="Выйти">Выйти</span>
          </div>
          <div class="login-name" style="display: none;"><span>{{ userName }}</span></div>          
        </div>        
    <div class="gears" style="display: none;"><img class="agears" src="/source/img/gears.svg" alt="*"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 1181px){

    .top-menu{
        top: 24px !important;
        height: 44px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: transparent;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .logo {
    transform: scale(1);
    margin-right: 0;
    float: left;
    }

}



@media (max-width: 1083px){

    .ph-lift.mobile-menu{
        /*display: block;*/
        background-color: rgba(30, 35, 41, 0.7);
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    .ph-lift.mobile-menu ul li{
        float: none;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    .top-menu{
        top: 0 !important; 
        padding: 10px 0px;
        height: auto;
        background-color: rgba(30, 35, 41, 0.7);
        text-align: center;
    }

    .hamburger-menu{
        display: block;
        float: left;
        padding-top: 18px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }


        .logo{
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            transform: scale(0.78);
            margin-right: -58px;
            float: none;
        }

        .login{
            transform: scale(0.7);
            margin-right: -15px;
        }
    }

.logo{
    float: left;

}

.top-menu{
    position: absolute;
    top:-68px;
    height: 44px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;    
}

.ph-lift ul{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 22px 0 0 25px;
}

.ph-lift ul li {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;

}
.login{
    float: right;
    padding-top: 18px;
}
```

Comment: With `max-width` you will need to rewrite the rules as it gets smaller, for example, your base styles will need to be for the largest possible, and then as your browser gets smaller, add in `@media (max-width: 1083px)` to change some of the styles as needed.

Comment: hm, everything is as you talking.  But it doesn't work... Unfortunataly

Comment: Which rules are causing you issues? What do you want the nav to look like at what sizes?